# Boxplot - grouped data - Python (only frequency known)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, boxplot

I'm starting to use Jupyter and Pandas library and I have a trouble with the boxplot graphic.
I have the next dataframe:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7zlo.png)

The problem with this dataframe is that I only have the data for frequency in different range of values. How could I make a graphic with this kind of value table? I'd like to make a boxplot for each column of frequency.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure that I understand your question well but here is a demo for boxplot visualization hope its helps

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        # a custom dataframe
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(1, 10, 5),
                           'B': np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)})
        # and your first column
df['E'] = pd.Series(['0-6', '7-13', '14-20', '21-27', '28-34'
                            ])
print(df)
df.boxplot(column=['A', 'B'], 
by='E',vert=True,showmeans=True,meanline=True,showfliers=False)
plt.show()
```